Model designer crashes when applying layer styles
I have a problem with the designer model.
I'm looking to automate the application of layer styles via the model designer. I have several layers over several years using the same style that I saved. So I put an “Apply style” algorithm for each of my layers as in the example below.

When I run the algorithm, it crashes but never at the same time. the example that I give you, crashed at 35% of the execution while the time before, it crashed at 85% and again before at 65%
Here is the error I have:
Python Stack Trace
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x000050ac (most recent call first):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py", line 152 in runModel
    dlg.exec_()


Stack Trace


QgsExpressionContextScope::addVariable :
QgsProject::createExpressionContextScope :
QgsExpressionContextUtils::globalProjectLayerScopes :
QgsLayerTreeModelLegendNode::createTemporaryRenderContext :
QgsSymbolLegendNode::data :
QgsLayerTreeModel::legendIconEmbeddedInParent :
QgsLayerTreeModel::data :
QSortFilterProxyModel::data :
QModelIndex::data :
QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption :
QStyledItemDelegate::paint :
QgsLayerTreeViewIndicator::QgsLayerTreeViewIndicator :
QTreeView::drawRow :
QTreeView::drawTree :
QTreeView::paintEvent :
QWidget::event :
QFrame::event :
QAbstractItemView::viewportEvent :
QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget :
QWidgetPrivate::moveRect :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QDialog::exec :
PyInit_QtWidgets :
PyObject_Str :
PyEval_EvalFrameDefault :
PyFunction_Vectorcall :
PyFunction_Vectorcall :
PyObject_GC_Del :
PyVectorcall_Call :
PyObject_Call :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
PyInit_QtCore :
QObject::qt_static_metacall :
QAction::activate :
QAbstractButton::click :
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify :
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :




QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.34.3-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 47373234ac
Compiled against Qt: 5.15.3
Running against Qt: 5.15.3
Compiled against GDAL: 3.8.3
Running against GDAL: 3.8.3



System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.22621


Are those 'apply style' algorithms linked sequentially, or are you applying multiple 'single' styes? If multiple singles - I wonder if the threading is causing the inconsistent completion, and you may be able to identify the style causing the fault by applying the processing step as a batch process
